# Cleanest way of dealing with different argument types

Tags: php, coding-style, arguments

I have the following piece of code, which generates six drop-down elements:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
        $RelatedProductsHtmlList .= $this->getRelatedProductHtmlDropdown($Products[$i], $allAvailibleProducts, $i);
    }
```

In this code, the argument `$Products[$i]` is passed, which is a ORM object with information for setting the default selected value of the drop-down list that is generated. I have the problem that `$Products` is not always an array. Sometimes only contains one value, in which case it's not an array, but a single ORM object.

What is the cleanest thing to do? Convert `$Products` to an array with only one element? Always pass the entire `$Products` variable en determine in the function if it's an array? Or determine if `$Products` is an array before calling the function and set the function argument accordingly?

Comment: The real fix would be to fix the code that generates `$products` to always return an array, it's bad design to have an api that returns different data types depending on size.

Comment: I agree. However, I'm using PHP activerecord as an ORM, which gives me this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: fix it before calling the method or inside the method itself.

Example:

```
if(!is_array($products)) {
    $products = array($product));
}
```

If you ask me, I would add this code to the top of the method itself as this would ease the function call and reduce redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to allow to pass array and a single object into a function. You will avoid multiple checks in different parts of code. You can do it this way:

```
/**
@param array | ProductClass $Products
...
*/
public function getRelatedProductHtmlDropdown($Products, $allAvailibleProducts, $i)
{
    if (!is_array($Products)) $Products = array($Products);
    ....
}
```